# 'If' condition is true but 'else' is being executed

Tags: android, eclipse

The `if` condition is true but the code in `else` snippet gets executed.

[image]

I have already tried restarting the Eclipse, it didn't help.

Comment: Can you use `Log.i(...)` to output that expression value? have you tried to `Clean and Build` the project?

Comment: Do you have multiple threads accessing that stream? Maybe it's playing in the background.

Comment: How can you be certain that at time you evaluate the watch, it has the same value as when it's tested with the if statement?

Comment: @Wakim in LogCat it's giving different values. The condition is `false` there and the `getCurrentPosition()` of `MediaPlayer` is giving non-zero value.

Comment: @kichik no, only one thread.

Comment: So what type is `mPlayer`? It might be using IPC which can also explain this.

Comment: @kichik it is default `MediaPlayer` object.

Comment: Need more code context then. Are you using the async API or the normal one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are two problems.

**Problem 1:**

First problem was with `getCurrentPosition()` method of the `MediaPlayer`

```
mediaPlayer.stop();
mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(); // The current position in milliseconds
```

In the above code, the second line returns `8549` while the mediaPlayer was stopped already. I was asuming that after stoping the media player, the `getCurrentPosition` method will return zero milliseconds.

**Problem 2:**

The second problem (which is actually the answer to this post) was with the debugger. It seems its a bug in debugger.

```
mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() // value in debugger is 0 (as shown in the screenshot in OP)
mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() == 0 // value in debugger is true (as shown in the screenshot in OP)
```

But when I log the exact same thing in logcat, it gives different results:

```
Log.d("pos", mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()+""); // prints a non-zero value in log, in my case 8549
Log.d("con", String.valueOf( mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() == 0 ) ); // prints a false value in log
```

Which clearly shows why the `else` code snippet was being executed and why we should not blindly rely on the debugger sometimes :-P

**Summary**

Whenever you see such dramatic behaviour in debugger, try logging the variables in logcat. (Credit goes to Wakim, because his comment gave me the direction)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

> mPlayer.getCurrentPosition().equals("0")

also try placing the codes in if block in else block (vice versa)